# PHP Loop through keys. Group matching values, calculate keys value

Tags: php, html, arrays

This is my PHP array:

```
Array (
  [0] => Array ( [heigth] => 6300 [type] => A [length] => 2370 )
  [1] => Array ( [heigth] => 1150 [type] => B [length] => 5510 )
  [2] => Array ( [heigth] => 1150 [type] => C [length] => 7150 )
  [3] => Array ( [heigth] => 1150 [type] => A [length] => 3540 )
);
```

Now i'd like to calculate total area for each type.
You can see that type "A" exists 2 times.

So I need to loop through my array, group types and calculate heigth * length.

I guess my problem is that "type" can be anything. I cannot hardcode them.

So let's start:

```
for($i = 0; $i < $rowCountArray; $i++){
  //Grab type
  $type = $array[$i]['type'];
  //Calc Area
  $area = $array[$i]['heigth'] * $array[$i]['length'];

  //Here i need something like an if statement. But also i need dynamic added vars?!
  //if(type is NEW) if(type exists) 

  $type1_Area += $area; //Seperated by types
  $type2_Area += $area; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about building an array of sums?

```
$arrSums= array();
for($i = 0; $i < $rowCountArray; $i++){

  $type = $array[$i]['type'];
  $arrSums[$type] += $array[$i]['heigth'] * $array[$i]['length'];
}

// display the array elements with sums
foreach ($arrSums as $key => $value) {
  print sprintf('sum for %s is: %d', $key, $value);
}
print sprintf('total sum is: %d', array_sum($arrSums));
```

Comment: Very nice. Works like a charm. I will read up on "print" and "sprintf" because i usualy use "echo". Now i don´t know how to get more decimals?! Thank you!

Comment: You can either use `print` or `echo`, IMHO it doesn't really matter. [sprintf](http://us2.php.net/sprintf) is pretty useful in case you wish to output formatted strings but I wouldn't recommend it if you need to use many variables. Could you explain a bit more what you meant with "how to get more decimals"?

Comment: Ok. Thank you. Well if i use your "print" code. I don´t get any decimals at all. Only full numbers like: 1. But if i echo i can have 1.345 I like echo so i use it ;D

Comment: I see, I didn't expect any decimal values. Instead of using `%d` (decimals) in the sprintf() lines, use `%f`(floats) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but this should work?

You just want to set the area to 0 if it's not already in the array, and then you have each type's total area to do with as you wish.

```
$arr = array(
  array('height' => 6300, 'type' => 'A', 'length' => 2370),
  array('height' => 1150 , 'type' => 'A', 'length' => 5510 ),
  array('height' => 1150 , 'type' => 'A', 'length' => 7150),
  array('height' => 1150 , 'type' => 'A', 'length' => 3540 ),
);

$area = array();

foreach ($arr AS $item) {
  if (!isset($area[$item['type']])) $area[$item['type']] = 0;
  $area[$item['type']] += $item['type'] * $item['length'];
}
```